# zend driven web site does not recognize result of custom functions defined in google spreadsheet if target sheet is not open/active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, zend-gdata

I am using the Zend Gdata library to build a website using content from a Google Spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet contains many custom functions.  If the target spreadsheet is open/active, all of the content in the resulting web site is updated/correct.  If the target spreadsheet is NOT open/active, only the "text" from the target spreadsheet cells makes it to the web site, but any cell that involves a custom function displays as #N/A.  Is there a way to trigger the custom functions to run in a Google spreadsheet without opening it?

Comment: I should clarify that on further investigation it seems the web page renders before all of the custom functions have time to process in the target spreadsheet.  After several reloads the page has complete data.  If the target spreadsheet is open - the processing time is cut down.  Any suggestions on how to delay the page rendering until functions have run?

Answer (score 0):

me too. Is an old problem, I did file an issue for it about 1 year ago. "Custom functions often return #N/A" http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1131

Suggest you star it and add a comment, might help.

Looks like the problem is not limited to GAS